# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError) timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Have tried the following under windows environment

1. Copied the certificate file.
2. Tried to run gem update --system
3. Ran the whole thing as administrator
4. Was planning to use rails 5.1.0
5. Ruby was 2.3.3
6. Have tried it with previous versions also and the point is it never works with a WIFI connection. When this is run over a cabled network it seems to download things and work properly on previous versions of Rails and Ruby

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800432/gem-cannot-access-rubygems-org , but for Windows.